# How to highlight all repeated text in Notepad using C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

How can I highlight all repeated text by double clicking on a word in `Notepad`?

I want Notepad to act like notepad++ in highlighting text when I select a word repeated inside the content.

I am familiar with some `pInvoke` materials and concepts. My C# project handles all processes needed for getting Notepad instances, handles etc. But I couldn't figure out how to send back color to notepad edit control?

What I need is your advice and road-map for the matter. Which subject should I cover to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think you can magically make notepad do this?

Comment: In fact, notepad is just an example, I have another app to which I need to apply this solution. If I manage this in Notepad, I can do it everywhere having edit control outside from my c# app.

Comment: I don't understand how people downvoted the issue. Is it really nonsense?

Comment: Well, the first thing to ask is: do you have any reason to think that this is *possible*? Have you seen this done before? Not everything is possible, or at least: if it is possible, it will have to be done using a ton of hacks upon hacks upon hacks and will be massively brittle, and it is unlikely that it will have a simple answer

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this to Notepad.  Notepad uses a plain edit control, which doesn't support colored text ranges.  You need to wrap a rich edit control to do this (or use the Scintilla edit control, which Notepad++ does).

Comment: Okay, what if I try to do this for notepad++ which does support highlighting, what would i need?

Comment: Well according to the [Scintilla Documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html), you would get the window handle & send messages to it.  The relevant messages look like SCI_SETINDICATORCURRENT and SCI_SETINDICATORFILLRANGE.

Answer (score 0):

This page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd885121.aspx) from MSDN seems exactly what you're looking for.

From MSDN:
*You can add different visual effects to the editor by creating Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) component parts. This walkthrough shows how to highlight every occurrence of the current word in a text file. If a word occurs more than one time in a text file, and you position the caret in one occurrence, every occurrence is highlighted*

This will guide you on how to create an application that when you highlight a word it will highlight all matching words in Blue.

If you're not looking for a full solution then the concept is there and it is explained well.

Comment: He mentions his C# project and he wants notepad with that functionality, the MSDN page I listed basically allows you to open the application then highlight any text with a text file (notepad) to highlight all other words. - I am being presumptuous in assuming he's using Visual Studio I guess.

Comment: given that it talks about pInvoke and "Notepad instances, handles etc" - I genuinely do think he's referring to regular vanilla notepad.

Comment: Well I possibly misunderstood the question, if he's talking about a notepad without using VS then I don't even understand the question, I mean is it even possible? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: As Marc understood, I meant classic notepad.exe which I want to highlight text. For example, when I select a word inside notepad.exe, my app listen all events of it, then it will find repeated words inside the Edit Control of Notepad and highlight all of them.

Comment: That's exactly what the application I linked does?

Comment: @SamN no, the linked application is creation a Visual Studio extension. It changes what happens *inside Visual Studio*, using the Visual Studio SDK / API to talk to Visual Studio

Comment: Ah I see, apologies for my misunderstanding, but maybe some of the C# code is relevant?

Comment: @SamN - no, unfortunately; the VS extension kit is pretty specific to Visual Studio.